# How to add geom_text in ggarrange?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I get warning message :

```
In as_grob.default(plot) : Cannot convert object of class LayerInstanceLayerggprotogg into a grob.
```

The `geom_text` I would like to add is `geom_text(aes(label = rownames(data)), size = 4)`.

If I add it in the `ggplot` function, I get this warning message ,When trying to run the `ggarrange` :

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (87): label
```

```
mgp_df = ggplot2::mpg
mpg_df2 = mgp_df[1:50,]

rownames(mgp_df)<-make.names(mgp_df$manufacturer, unique = TRUE)

p1<-ggplot(mgp_df, aes(x=cty, y=hwy)) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm)+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_text(aes(label = rownames(mgp_df)), size = 4) +
  scale_x_continuous(name="testx")+
  scale_y_continuous(name="testy", limits=c(35, 90))

p2<-ggplot(mpg_df2, aes(x=cty, y=hwy)) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm)+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_text(aes(label = rownames(mpg_df2)), size = 4) +
  scale_x_continuous(name="testx")+
  scale_y_continuous(name="testy", limits=c(35, 90))

figure <- ggarrange(p1, p2,
                    labels = c("test1", "  test2"),
                    ncol = 1, nrow = 2)
figure
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a column in `data` for the labels:

```
data$labs <- rownames(data)
```

Then change `geom_text` to:

```
geom_text(aes(label = labs), size = 4)
```

Comment: I have, but it doesn't allow me to plot it when using ggarrange. I am able to plot 1 plot using ggplot, but if I try stacking it becomes a problem with the "aestetichs" I am unsure why that is.

Comment: can you post to code you are currently using?

Comment: It seems to come from that the dataset has different sizes. It works in this code here, but when I run it with my original code the problem occurs. Not sure why.